# How to use max statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have table Product(ProductID, Name, Price).
I should create a script which returnes Name and Prices, for the 10 most expensive items using MAX statement.

Comment: I believe you do not need MAX for such task, just `ORDER BY Price DESC` and return `LIMIT 10`

Comment: I would change the question title to: _"When to use max statement"_ **...**

Comment: @gdoron: `MAX()` is a function.

Comment: @onedaywhen. `blue` is a color. :-) look at the current question title.

Comment: @gdoron: then the question should be, *Does SQL have a max statement?*, to which the answer would be, *No, but it does have a `MAX()` function* :)

Answer (score 8):

What you want is probably more like

```
SELECT TOP 10 ProductID, Name, Price
FROM Product
ORDER BY Price DESC
```

Or, for MySQL,

```
SELECT ProductID, Name, Price
FROM PRODUCT
ORDER BY Price DESC
LIMIT 10
```

`MAX` wouldn't work very well -- it's an "aggregate function", meaning it works with groups.  And you don't have anything to group by; each item is independent of the others, if i understand your database structure correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You only want to use `MAX()` if you want the most expensive item.  Since you want the ten most expensive, `order by price desc` and select the top 10 records:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ProductId, Name, Price
FROM Product
ORDER BY Price Desc
```